# ArcMap does not open

Tags: arcmap

I can open a new ArcMap window and do everything, but I cannot open an existing ArcMap file! Nothing happens when I click on an Arcmap.mxd file that I created before. It never opens it! I cannot access neither of my files! I can make new files, but when I save them and close the file, it doesn't get opened again.

Comment: what version are you running? Can you open the same .mxd's from a different machine on the network? can you login a different user profile and see if the files open?

Comment: Have you tried running the MXD Doctor? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/administering-desktop/using-the-mxd-doctor-utility.htm

Comment: Its version 10.5. Other laptops cannot also open the files.

Comment: Step 4. https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile rename (or delete) normal.mxt

Comment: When I open a new empty arcmap file, I can then open my previous existing .mxd files through file> open.     But when I click on a file directly, it fails to open!

Comment: It sounds like there may be something wrong with the mxd filetype registration. Have you tried to repair or reinstall ArcGIS? You could also try to right click on the mxd, select *Open With* and then browse to the Arcmap.exe executable.

Comment: I've had that same problem before and running the mxd doctor fixed the problem. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/administering-desktop/using-the-mxd-doctor-utility.htm

Answer (score 1):

Have you started your personal investigation? This is what I usually do.

1. Do not freak out
2. Be methodic, ask yourself what causes the problem. It can only be 2 things, the software not being able to open itself, or the file being corrupted. Revise the task manager, whats going on?
3. Check online if someone else has had the same issue, be handy with your keywords.[arcgis](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008840)
4. If it is the software, reinstall it after making sure you know how to reinstall it (license wise) and without deleting your personal config files, if you have them.
5. In case you suspect it is the file, check the saving options.